# How the get the whole source html code of a webpage that is generated by Javascript using Java / Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie in programming and I have a task here I need to solve. I am trying to get the html source code of a webpage using Java / Webdriver method `getPageSource()`. Problem is, that page is somehow generated, probably by javascript, so the result I get is html code containing just page skeleton - a table that is empty, not filled by data. But, there is tag like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/x/js/main.c0e805a3.js"></script>` in the very bottom of that html code.
The question is, how can I force Webdriver to run that Javascript and give me the result - the whole source html with data. I already tried to use this `(js.executeScript("window.location = '/x/js/main.c0e805a3.js'");)` before calling `getPageSource()` but not successful.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few setups, now, that can run the Java-Script on a web-page.  The most well known, I think, is likely `Selenium` since I think it has been around for a while.   Others include `karate`, `Puppeteer`, and even an old tool called `Rhino`.  Puppeteer is a Google, Inc. project that uses Java-Script (server-side Java-Script, called `Node.js`.  They don't like us comparing, contrasting libraries here.

I haven't had the time to engage Selenium, yet, but I write HTML parser, search and update code all the time.  If your only goal is to load a page whose contents are dynamically "filled in by AJAX calls" - and what I mean by that, you only want the contents of an HTML that would normally see when you visit the sites web-page, ***and you are not concerned with button presses*** then the one I have been using for that is called ***`Splash`***  This tool does have the ability to let you invoke Java-Script, but if all you want to do is see the JS on a page dynamically load the table, then, literally, all you have to do is start-the tool, and add one line to your program.

On Google Cloud Platform, these 2 lines will start a ***Splash Proxy Server***.  If you are writing your code on AWS (Amazon) or Azure (Microsoft), it would likely be similar.  If you are running your code in an office on the local machine, you would have to research how to start it.

> Install Docker. Make sure Docker version >= 17 is installed.
>
> Pull the image:
>
> ```
>  $ sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash
> ```
>
> Start the container:
>
> ```
> $ sudo docker run -it -p 8050:8050 --rm scrapinghub/splash
> ```

Then, in your code, all you have to do is the following:

```
// If your original code looked like this:
URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

Change the first line of code in this example to this, and (theoretically), and dynamically loaded HTML tables that are completed with the `onload` page events will be automatically loaded before returning the HTML page.

```
// Add this line to your methods
String splashProxy = "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=";
URL url = new URL(splashProxy + "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus");
```

For most web-sites, any initial tables that are filled by JS/jQuery/AJAX will be filled in.  If you are willing to learn teh `Lua Programming Language`, you can also start invoking the methods there.  It has been pretty convenient for my purposes, since I am not writing web-page testing code (code that simulates user button presses).  If that is what you are doing, Selenium is likely worth spending time learning / studying the A.P.I.